# asp.net mvc groupbox is not wrapping around the textbox controls

Tags: asp-net-mvc-1

I am trying to create a group box around some textbox control. Here is my code so far:

```
 <form method="POST" name="frmInfo" id="Info">
        <fieldset class="box-border">
            <legend class="box-border">My Information</legend>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

When the page is rendered, I only see the group name and one line above the textboxes but there is not groupbox wrapping around the textbox. How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could because of you **class="box-border"** overriding the styles

Try Removing it . I hope it will solve your problem